# Can't view newly added content in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I get following error message in WordPress.

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I am new to WordPress and I was following a tutorial how to develop WP plugins.

Basically, I loaded a plugin in admin menu and activated it.

This code is included in **init.php** file.

```
    function oscimp_admin() {
                include('oscommerce_import_admin.php');
            }
            //when the menu is click 4th parameter  will be trugger
            function oscimp_admin_actions() {
                add_options_page("OSCommerce Product Display", "Menuka  Product Display", 1, "OSCommerce Product Display", "oscimp_admin");
            }

            add_action('admin_menu', 'oscimp_admin_actions');

    I have included following code in oscommerce_import_admin.php file
   <?php 
    if($_POST['oscimp_hidden'] == 'Y') {
        //Form data sent
        $dbhost = $_POST['oscimp_dbhost'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbhost', $dbhost);

        $dbname = $_POST['oscimp_dbname'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbname', $dbname);

        $dbuser = $_POST['oscimp_dbuser'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbuser', $dbuser);

        $dbpwd = $_POST['oscimp_dbpwd'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbpwd', $dbpwd);

        $prod_img_folder = $_POST['oscimp_prod_img_folder'];
        update_option('oscimp_prod_img_folder', $prod_img_folder);

        $store_url = $_POST['oscimp_store_url'];
        update_option('oscimp_store_url', $store_url);
        ?>
        <div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Options saved.' ); ?></strong></p></div>
        <?php
    } else {
        //Normal page display
        $dbhost = get_option('oscimp_dbhost');
        $dbname = get_option('oscimp_dbname');
        $dbuser = get_option('oscimp_dbuser');
        $dbpwd = get_option('oscimp_dbpwd');
        $prod_img_folder = get_option('oscimp_prod_img_folder');
        $store_url = get_option('oscimp_store_url');
    }


?>      

<div class="wrap">
            <?php  //  echo "<h2>" . __( 'OSCommerce Product Display Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

            <form name="oscimp_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="oscimp_hidden" value="Y">
                <?php    echo "<h4>" . __( 'OSCommerce Database Settings', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h4>"; ?>
                <p><?php _e("Database host: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbhost" value="<?php echo $dbhost; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: localhost" ); ?></p>
                <p><?php _e("Database name: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbname" value="<?php echo $dbname; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: oscommerce_shop" ); ?></p>
                <p><?php _e("Database user: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbuser" value="<?php echo $dbuser; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: root" ); ?></p>
                <p><?php _e("Database password: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbpwd" value="<?php echo $dbpwd; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: secretpassword" ); ?></p>
                <hr />
                <?php    echo "<h4>" . __( 'OSCommerce Store Settings', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h4>"; ?>
                <p><?php _e("Store URL: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_store_url" value="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: http://www.yourstore.com/" ); ?></p>
                <p><?php _e("Product image folder: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_prod_img_folder" value="<?php echo $prod_img_folder; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: http://www.yourstore.com/images/" ); ?></p>


                <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Update Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) ?>" />
                </p>
            </form>
</div>
```

When I go to administration menu link I get error mentioned above. Is there any clue to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your call to add_options_page does add a new option under settings but the problem is when you click on it.

If you check the [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) you can see that the 4th parameter is called menu_slug and it is something that gets added to the URL (in get to options-general.php in this case). So the first thing would be to change that to something that is a bit more "url friendly". So for example try to switch "OSCommerce Product Display" to "oscommerce-product-display"

Also, the 3rd parameter is called capability and this must be a string representing an action that the user must be able to perform. If you want to allow only the admin to access this option you could use 'install_plugins' (for example) instead of 1. You can see a full list of roles and capabilities here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table

So the line that adds your menu option should become something like

```
add_options_page("OSCommerce Product Display", "Menuka  Product Display", 'install_plugins', "oscommerce-product-display", "oscimp_admin");
```

From that point on you just need to be sure that oscimp_admin is a valid callback (a function that renders that page you need).